# Calling count method of std::set of pointers with const key type reference

Tags: c++, stl, constants

I have a class like

```
struct S {

    bool foo(const AType& v) const {
        return values.count(&v); // compile error due to the constness of v
    }

    private:
        std::set<AType*> values;
};
```

This is a simplified version. In real code, foo does some complex things.
The code produces an error

```
invalid conversion from ‘const AType*’ to ‘std::set<AType*>::key_type {aka AType*}’
```

I think foo should take 'const AType& v' because it does not mutate v.
The type of the member variable 'values' can not be std::set<const AType*> because some methods of the struct S call non-const methods of the elements contained in 'values'.
I can cast constness of 'v' away:

```
bool foo(const AType& v) const {
    return values.count((AType*) &v);
}
```

But I think this may not be a good solution in general.
What solution could I have?

Comment: I don't see any harm in using `values.count(const_cast<AType*>(&v));` since you are going to compare only pointers.

Comment: Same as usual pointer annoyance a `T const *` is not convertible to `T* const` and vice versa.

Comment: Are you sure that you want count by pointers but not the object value?

Comment: @R Sahu, I believe the count method of std::set does not mutate its arguemnt. But there could be similar situation with types other than std::set and could break const-correctness.

Comment: @strugi Note: count and find are equivalent, here

Comment: @Andrew, then it should be `bool foo(const AType* const v)`. I don't need to mutate v.

Comment: @Dieter Lücking, find produces the same error. It does not change the nature of the problem.

Comment: @strugi is it possible to make std::set<const AType*> ?

Comment: and whats wrong with bool foo(const AType* const v) ?

Comment: @strugi Which is nice (the functions are equivalent in a set)

Comment: @mirt, see my post for the first question and, for the second question, it produces the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template<class T>
struct const_ptr_compare:std::less<T const*> {
  typedef void is_transparent;
};

std::set<AType*, const_ptr_compare<AType>> values;
```

and bob is your uncle.

I defined a comparator that can transparently handle `T const*` comparisons as well as `T*` comparisons.  I then told `std::set` that it is transparent.

The `is_transparent` technique is a C++14 enhancement to `std::set`.  Your compiler may already have support for it.

---

If you want to be able to pass in base-classes-of-`T` a bit more work needs to be done.  You need a function object that tests its two arguments (each pointers to const) to see which is a base class of the other, and does a `std::less<base const*>{}(lhs, rhs)` using that base class.  However, that is going further down the rabbit hole than we need to.

---

A C++11/03 approach could involve making the editable portions of `AType` `mutable`, and having a `const AType*` `set`.  Failing that, a `const_cast<AType*>` is reasonable.

Please don't use a C-style cast: they are almost never required, and they can be accidentally too powerful.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is this:

> The type of the member variable 'values' can not be std::set because some methods of the struct S call non-const methods of
>   the elements contained in 'values'.

You are not supposed to mutate the set key in any way.

You should be using a `map`, where the actual key parts are in the key and are `const`, and the mutating parts are in the value and are non-`const`.

If this is impractical for your design, I understand. The `const_cast` workaround will solve the issue. It feels inelegant, but that's because your usage of `set` is inelegant.

Answer (score 0):

This is just one of the many problems of the const correctness concept: it doesn't scale by composition.

The casting solution is just ok, if you feel it's "dirty" in some way probably you're overestimating cleanness of the `const` concept.

Consider that defining special types for `const_iterator` and `const_reverse_iterator` was needed or that sometimes const correctness requires actual code duplication (e.g. in many cases for `operator[]`) or that if you've an object containing a non-const pointer you can mutate the pointed-to object freely and even delete it in const members.

Your cast doesn't look that bad in comparison :-)